# ClassCastException with Primefaces GMap OverlaySelect event

Tags: jsf, primefaces, classcastexception, primefaces-gmap

I want to show some data inside infoWindow of Gmap. the code is as follow:

```
<p:gmap center="#{mybean.latitude}, #{mybean.longitude}" zoom="15" 
                    type="ROADMAP" model="#{mybean.mymapModel}" >
        <p:ajax event="overlaySelect" listener="#{mybean.onMarkerSelect}" />  
        <p:gmapInfoWindow >  
            <div class="popup_title prem">Address:</div>
            <div class="popup_address">#{mybean.markerAll.street}, #{mybean.markerAll.zipcode} #{mybean.markerAll.city}</div>
        </p:gmapInfoWindow>  
</p:gmap>
```

and My ManagedBean

```
public void onMarkerSelect(OverlaySelectEvent event) {
        marker = (Marker) event.getOverlay();
        markerAll = (myHelperClass) marker.getData();
    }
```

Everything is working fine in development on my local computer. When the marker is clicked, the data (address) shows up in the infoWindow.

On production I see a lot of `ClassCastException` like:

```
FullAjaxExceptionHandler: An exception occurred during processing JSF ajax request. Error page '/error.jsf' will be shown.    
    java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast 
        to com.mypackage.util.myHelperClass
        at com.mypackage.myBean.onMarkerSelect(myBean.java:416)
...
...
```

The property `data` of the `org.primefaces.model.map.Marker` is of type `Object` and not `String`!

What am I doing wrong? And why this works sometime and sometimes not?

I'm using Primefaces 5.3.7

Comment: i can't really tell you why its behaving inconsistent, but is there something that speaks against just checking `if(marker.getData() instanceof myHelperClass)` before you cast?

Comment: And did you check what the string contains? All simple things you  (and only you) can check yourself

Comment: The Logging returns as expected `com.mypackage.util.MyHelperClass@47535504`. It doesn't return a string. This is why I'm reporting this here.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's missing the uppercase letter m - myHelperClass by MyHelperClass

```
public void onMarkerSelect(OverlaySelectEvent event) {
    marker = (Marker) event.getOverlay();
    markerAll = (MyHelperClass) marker.getData();
}
```

Comment: :-)... Then the application won't even compile... And it is impossible to then work sometimes and not in other situations. Although it is uncommon in java, it is technically not wrong to start a class name with a lower case\

Comment: @Kukeltje, excatly.It was just a typo.